# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter in Django while trying add item to favorite

Tags: python, django

Can someone please help me?

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to change the icon color when added to favorites.

Is there any solution for this error?

**This is the view where I'm adding my post to Favorite:**

```
@login_required
def favourite_post(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Car, id=id)

    if post.favourite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.favourite.remove(request.user)
    else:
        post.favourite.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

**This is my Model**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)
```

**And this where I want to send is_favourite bool which show is added to favorite or not**

```
def show_all_car_page(request):
    filtered_cars = CarFilter(
        request.GET,
        queryset=Car.objects.all()
    )

    paginator = Paginator(filtered_cars.qs, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)

    is_favourite = bool
    if filtered_cars.Meta.model.favourite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_favourite = True
    context = {
        'filtered_cars': filtered_cars,
        'posts': posts,
        'is_favourite': is_favourite
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

**And here CarFilter is my filter.py where i can filter my posts,**

```
class CarFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['brand', 'city', 'body_type', 'model', 'year', 'transmission']
```

**And also in my template I'm doing like this :**

```
 {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
     <a href="{% url 'car:favourite_post' id=car.id %}" title="Seçilənlərə Əlavə et">

          {% if is_favourite %}
             <i class="fas fa-heart" style="color: red"></i>
          {% else %}
              <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
          {% endif %}
     </a>
  {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'user:login' %}" title="Seçilənlərə Əlavə et">
              <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
       </a>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you're trying to `filter` using an instance (single object) of the `Car` table.

What you need to do is to filter using the class itself. For example;

```
car = Car.objects.first()

users_cars = Car.favourite.through.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
```

What you're doing with `.add()` and `.remove()` is correct though. These are done on an instance of the model.

Comment: @SahinPashayev excellent news. Could you mark this answer as accepted to show this question as having been answered?

Comment: I did, but now I have another problem that when I'm adding my post to favorites all my posts icons changing, but I want only which I added could you please help me about this?

Comment: @SahinPashayev Hopefully. Post another question & I'll keep an eye out!